# Instrument memory leak under ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

I've rebuild my app, I found that it would use a lot of memory. Before, it keeps under 20M memories. Now it's up to 70M memories.

When I use Instrument to analysis memory leaks. I got this

[image]

When I click it for details. It says the memory leaks in main.m

[image]

Why does it show 100% leak?

How can I fix this problem? Or please some advice about find out my leak problem and the way to fix it. Thanks

Comment: It means all the leaks are in the app.  More information is required to provide more detail.

Comment: In ARC, memory leaks are often created by circular references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313967/arc-circular-reference-in-objective-c-uses-delegate

Answer (score 0):

It shows a 100% memory leak because main () is where your application starts. 100% of the memory leaks in your application are in your application. Kind of obvious really, isn't it?

You need to find a more specific place. Maybe it's time to learn the difference between weak and strong references as well. (See Quentin's comment).

Does your memory use increase over time, or does it stop at 70 MB? What actions increase memory use?